# Задать переменной background color

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, aspx

у меня есть веб-форма на ASP.NET и в файле aspx.cs необходимо задать переменной бэкграунд цвет. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?
Использую Label на aspx странице, в самом лейбле есть текст и целочисленная переменная, вот эту переменную нужно и закрасить в какой-либо цвет, в гугле забанили, ибо найти могу только на win formsах, но не для .net

Comment: ну дак и в чем проблема? У вас в label нет цвета фона или что?

Comment: `if (countPercent < MinPercent)
            {LabelPrihod.BackgroundColor = "Black"; }` Ругается на BackgroundColor не может распознать символ, в aspx.cs как его задать?

Comment: это мне что то должно расказать? )

Comment: вопрос лишь в том, как через aspx.cs задать цвет лэйблу

Comment: `LabelPrihod.BackgroundColor = "Black";` это не работает? Не красит? Ошибку выдает? Или в чем проблема?

Comment: да, не работает, не может распознать BackgroundColor

Comment: Так может `LabelPrihod.BackColor = Colors.Black;` ? [WebControl.BackColor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.backcolor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_BackColor)

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebControl.BackColor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.backcolor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_BackColor)

```
LabelPrihod.BackColor = Colors.Black;
```